# System Center Operations Manager 2016 API

Tags: scom, system-center

I am playing with System Center Operations Manager 2012 R2 and 2016, and I would like to integrate the overall SCOM status into another monitoring solution (Cacti).

Is there an API to query the status of the SCOM Management Server and the number of active alerts, unhealthy clients, etc..?

I tried searching online for WMI or API access, but I get swamped with articles, how to use SCOM to monitor WMI and other APIs, not the other way around.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, searching for SDK reveals the answer:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh329086.aspx